# VBScript not working on IE11 which has frames

Tags: vbscript, internet-explorer-11, frames

I have a code which is working perfectly fine in Excel VBA but when I am trying the same in VBscript, it is erroring out while looking for Frames on IE 11.
Name    Value
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'ieobjbtn.GetElementsByTagName'

```
Dim objLink, ieobjbtn1, ieobjbtn
Set objCollection = objIE.Document.frames
Set ieobjbtn = objCollection("toolbar").Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")     
'Script is giving mentioned error here
For Each objLink In ieobjbtn
    If InStr(objLink.innerHTML, "xxxxx.gif") > 0 Then
        objLink.Click
        Wait_Webpage
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

In the standard DOM the function is called `getElementsByTagName` - note the lowercase `g` at the start.

It wouldn't surprise me if older versions of IE supported case-insensitivity because that is normal in VBScript, but newer ones have withdrawn that feature. VBScript is rarely used in IE these days and is being dropped entirely in the Windows 10 version of IE.

''Update:''

The corrected version is:

```
Set objCollection = objIE.Document.frames
Set ieobjbtn = objCollection("toolbar").document.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

Comment: Sorry, that was commented, I have take out that part but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: That's odd. Your code doesn't call `GetElementsByTagName` on `ieobjbtn`. Are you sure that's the exact error message, and this is the exact code you're running?

Comment: The updated code worked fine with IE8. On IE11 it is giving   Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'objCollection(...).Document.GetElementsByTagName'

Comment: That error message makes more sense - see update, I'd guess it's because of case-sensitivity.

Comment: The only other suggestion I have is to try `document.getElementsByTagName` so both start with lowercase letters. But presumably `objIE.Document.frames`  should stay as it is.

Comment: @Daneil - wohooo... that worked.. thank you so much... Dan.. You rock...!!

Comment: @AV-In Glad to hear it! Remember, the best way to say thank you on Stack Overflow is to upvote and accept the answer :)